# Posting a form in an admin module

Tags: magento-1.9

Hi in a frontend module I made I use the following to post a form;

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('my-module/') ?>index/search">
```

and had a searchAction function to handle the form. I have tried doing something similair using some tips found online but still to no avail;

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("MYADMINFOLDER/MYMODULE/index/AttributeSet"); ?>">
```

Just wanting to know how to post to an admin form and where I'm going wrong! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('your_module_name*/your_controller_name/your_action_name');?>" id="edit_form">
        <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />

    </form>
```

Comment: nice one this sort of worked and didnt work lol! I did this: `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="edit_form" method="post" action="<?php echo Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl("adminfolder/module/index/myaction"); ?>">` it'll post but not to my action just the module index controller

Comment: so that will post to:
`mysite.com/index.php/adminfolder/mymodule/index/key/MYKEYHERE/`

Comment: nevermind sorted it by removing `/index` in the getUrl nice one

Answer (score 1):

The Url should be `adminhtml/yourmodule/index` and the controller should be located in `Yourmodule/controllers/Adminhtml/IndexController.php`

This was the router will know that the form is being posted to an admin controller.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your adminhtml routing in your config.xml file, could you please update your adminhtml routing part here?

```
<admin>
        <routers>
            <yourmodule>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Namespace_Yourmodule</module>
                    <frontName>yourmodule</frontName>
                </args>
            </yourmodule>
        </routers>
    </admin>
```

This code (inside your adminhtml block) will return you the right url

```
$this->getUrl('yourmodule/controller/action');
```

Here is that I used and it works. Please check frontName tag inside your config carefully.

Comment: Custom admin routes created like this are obsolete, and will no longer work as of 1.9.2.2.